# SQL Parser in Delphi for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, delphi, parsing

I am looking for a good SQL parser in Delphi (2010) for SQL Server. I need such thing to parse an query and extract: select list, where and order by clauses. It does not matter if it is a commercial or an open-source solution. It can also be a DLL (written in any language, of course) but I prefer a VCL component over a DLL.

Comment: Not the exact same question but might be worth a look: ttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/615608/need-in-sql-parser-on-delphi

Comment: Yeah, but it is for firebird, not for sql server. And there are differences between them.

Comment: With cte's, nested queries, insert/drop/update/alter/etc statements, this is non-trivial code. Really the only safe way to parse a sql server query is with sql server.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rafael Delphi comes with a sql parser located in the `DBCommon` unit

Check these functions

```
function NextSQLToken(var p: PAnsiChar; out Token: AnsiString; CurSection: TSQLToken): TSQLToken; overload;
function NextSQLToken(var p: PWideChar; out Token: WideString; CurSection: TSQLToken): TSQLToken; overload;
function NextSQLToken(var p: PChar; out Token: String; CurSection: TSQLToken): TSQLToken; overload;

function GetIndexForOrderBy(const SQL: WideString; DataSet: TDataSet): TIndexDef;
function GetTableNameFromSQL(const SQL: WideString): WideString;
function GetTableNameFromQuery(const SQL: Widestring): Widestring;
function AddParamSQLForDetail(Params: TParams; SQL: WideString; Native: Boolean; QuoteChar: WideString = ''): WideString;
function IsMultiTableQuery(const SQL: WideString): Boolean;
function SQLRequiresParams(const SQL: WideString): Boolean;

function NextSQLTokenEx(var p: PWideChar; out Token: UnicodeString; CurSection: TSQLToken; IdOption: IDENTIFIEROption): TSQLToken; overload;
function NextSQLTokenEx(var p: PWideChar; out Token: WideString; CurSection: TSQLToken; IdOption: IDENTIFIEROption): TSQLToken; overload;
function NextSQLTokenEx(var p: PAnsiChar; out Token: AnsiString; CurSection: TSQLToken; IdOption: IDENTIFIEROption): TSQLToken; overload;
function GetTableNameFromSQLEx(const SQL: WideString; IdOption: IDENTIFIEROption): WideString;
```

This is a very simple sample to show how parse a sql sentence and get all the elements.

```
uses
  TypInfo,
  DbCommon,
  SysUtils;


const
  StrSql ='Select Field1, Field2, 54 field3, Field4 from Mytable1 Order by Field1,Field5';

procedure ParseSql(Const Sql : string);
var
  SQLToken     : TSQLToken;
  CurSection   : TSQLToken;
  Start        : PWideChar;
  Token        : WideString;
  IdOption     : IDENTIFIEROption;
begin
  IdOption   :=idMixCase;
  Start      :=PWideChar(StrSql);
  CurSection := stUnknown;
  repeat
    SQLToken := NextSQLTokenEx(Start, Token, CurSection, IdOption);
    if SQLToken<>stEnd then
    Writeln(Format('Type %s Token %s', [GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TSQLToken), integer(SQLToken)),Token]));
    CurSection := SQLToken;
  until SQLToken in [stEnd];
end;



begin
  try
    ParseSql(StrSql);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

this will return

```
Type stSelect Token Select
Type stFieldName Token Field1
Type stFieldName Token Field2
Type stNumber Token 54
Type stFieldName Token field3
Type stFieldName Token Field4
Type stFrom Token from
Type stTableName Token Mytable1
Type stOrderBy Token Order by
Type stFieldName Token Field1
Type stFieldName Token Field5
```

Comment: Its really good, but it thinks that `TOP` is a field, but it is not of course.

Comment: It does not work well as I said. It fails on a lot of cases, like when you have `Table.Field` it returns `Table` as a field and `Field` as Field also. It fails on detecting `Count()`, `Sum()`, `Average` and `top` as well. Not good enough for what I am looking for, but thanks for your help.

Comment: @Rafael sorry for that, I will keep my answer , because can help you to somebody else in the future to parse simple sql sentences. another option is build your own parser based in this implementation (DbCommon) and reading an article like this http://www.felix-colibri.com/papers/db/sql_parser/sql_parser.html

Comment: I will accept your answer because it helped me create my own parser. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

check out: http://www.sqlparser.com/sql-parser-vcl.php

This is a very powerful sql parser and all in VCL